# Acceder a las variables envíadas con FCM en Activity

Tags: java, firebase, push-notification, android

Tengo una aplicación Android que carga una url en el `WebView`, he implementado las notificaciones de Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Mediante los datos personalizados de FCM quiero enviar la url a la que llevar el `WebView`.

[image: Captura de campos personalizados FCM]

Mi pregunta es: 
**¿De qué manera puedo acceder a la clave y el valor en el `Activity` donde se crea el `WebView` ?**

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el **servicio** donde recibes los mensajes push de FCM deberías tener un método `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` , ese objeto `RemoteMessage` representa el mensaje recibido y tiene el método [getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getData()) que expone los llave/valor que incluiste como adicionales en la notificación.

Para pasar es información al activity en cuestión deberás incluirlo en el Intent usado para invocarla, pasando la información como un `extra`.

Answer (score 1):

Es importante tener en cuenta que el método `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` no es invocado cuando la push llega con la app en background o cerrada.

En estos casos debes hacer uso de [intent filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) o recibir el intent con la información en tu main activity.